# Error "BIND VARIABLE "N" NOT DECLARED" when running PL/SQL program

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I cannot find the error in my question for factorial of a number , don't know why I am getting it

'''

```
SQL> declare
      2  n number;
      3  i number;
      4  fact number;
      5  begin
      6  n:=:n;
      7  i:=1;
      8  fact:=1;
      9  while i<=n loop then
     10  fact:=fact*i;
     11  i:=i+1;
     12  end loop;
     13  dbms_output.put_line('factorial of this number is ' ||fact);
     14  end;
     15
     16  /
    SP2-0552: Bind variable "N" not declared.
```

'''

Comment: What do you think line 6 does?

Comment: i have used := for the assignment statement and =:n will be used at runtime

Comment: :n is a bind variable, which if you are running this from sqlplus, you have not created or assigned a value.

Comment: Nice palindrome though :)

Answer (score 0):

As you're running it in SQL*Plus, use substitution (instead of bind) variable - reference it with `&n`, not `:n`:

Also, fix the loop; there's no `then`.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2          n number;
  3          i number;
  4          fact number;
  5  begin
  6      n := &n;
  7      i := 1;
  8      fact := 1;
  9
 10      while i <= n loop
 11         fact := fact * i;
 12         i := i + 1;
 13      end loop;
 14
 15      dbms_output.put_line('factorial of this number is ' || fact);
 16
 17  end;
 18  /
Enter value for n: 4
old   6:     n := &n;
new   6:     n := 4;
factorial of this number is 24

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```